# vb.net my.settings arraylist is not an instance of object

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

```
If My.Settings.Sup1 Is Nothing Then
        My.Settings.Sup1 = New Collections.ArrayList
        My.Settings.Sup1.Add(0)' array index can't be negative or less than 0
        My.Settings.Sup1.Add(0)
        My.Settings.Sup1.Add(0)
        My.Settings.Sup1.Add(0)
    End If
```

why would i even get this exception in the commented line, is there anything wrong with the above code

i tried insert and assigning a value to the current index and still i am getting the exception

Comment: in the `settings` tab under project properties, what is the type of sup1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an User Setting on the Project Properties → Settings Tab of Type `System.Collections.ArrayList` and it works as expected.  Not sure what your problem is your code looks fine, I would double check your `Type` and make sure it is correct.

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ran this in a WPF project.  I couldn't quit figure out how you got an array list under my app settings stuff so I used a System.Collection.Specialized.StringCollection. [right-mouse] "My Project", go to Settings, and add Sup1 in there as System.Collection.Specialized.StringCollection.  Leave value blank.

In the debugger it iterates over all the lines below just fine, no exceptions.

```
    Public Sub New()
    'assuming sup1 is supposed to be an System.Collection.Specialized.StringCollection as set in Project Properties
            If My.Settings.Sup1 Is Nothing Then
                ' -- replaced w string collection -- My.Settings.Sup1 = New Collections.ArrayList
                My.Settings.Sup1 = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
                My.Settings.Sup1.Add(0) ' array index can't be negative or less than 0
                My.Settings.Sup1.Add(0)
                My.Settings.Sup1.Add(0)
                My.Settings.Sup1.Add(0)
            End If
    End Sub
```